# WebUrlLoaderClient : Synchronous request timed out after 10

Tags: jquery, eclipse, cordova

I've been developing an android application using phonegap. In the app i use an xmlrpcrequest request. Sometimes when i make the request, maybe due to slow connection, the request is timed out and i get the following error

**E/WebUrlLoaderClient(574): Synchronous request timed out after 10 seconds for the 0th try**

Is there anyway to "catch" this error, or maybe increase the timeout time??

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21882438/975443

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem since I updated to phonegap 2.8.1, what version are you using?
It does not seem to listen to the ajax argument timeout at all:

```
var dataObj = { 'value': whatever'};
        //navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 25000, 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password));
            },
            success: post_succes,
            error: function(xhr, status, errThrown) {
                var out = "<br>Error status " + status;
                out += "<br>Error request status text: " + xhr.statusText;
                out += "<br>Error request status: " + xhr.status;
                out += "<br>Error request response text: " + xhr.responseText;
                out += "<br>Error response header: " + xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
                navigator.notification.alert(out);
            }
        });
```

I also tried to set this value in the java main: (I know this is not the right property... but desperate figuring it out...)

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 25000);
```

it keeps sticking to the 10 seconds....