# Synchronous Ajax Timeout in webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, webview

While doing a synchronous ajax request (GET) from javascript to a cross domain website from webview in Andriod, the request fails. 
The code is like below,

```
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false
  })
  .done(function ( data ) { fnSuccess(JSON.stringify(data)); });

  jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Failed with:"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown+"--"+jqXHR.status+"--"+jqXHR.responseText);
  });
```

The website is supposed to return me data in JSON format and the average response time is around 90 seconds.
The website url is like, https://abc.com/abc/123?a=1&b=2&c=3

Below log is shown when the Ajax request starts (adb logcat),
E/WebUrlLoaderClient(  924): Synchronous request timed out after 10 seconds for the 0th try, URL: https://abc.com/abc/123?a=1&b=2&c=3
E/WebUrlLoaderClient(  924): Synchronous request timed out after 10 seconds for the 1th try, URL: ...
E/WebUrlLoaderClient(  924): Synchronous request timed out after 10 seconds for the 2th try, URL: ...

After the 3rd line is logged, the ajax request changes the ready state to 4 and the response status to 0 instead of 200 and the response text is also null. This means it is timing out after 30 seconds (3 retries of 10 seconds each).

I went through the WebUrlLoaderClient.cpp from Android open source and found that the timeout and the number of retries are fixed to 10 and 3 respectively.

This same request is working fine in asynchronous mode.

Please let me know whether I am doing anything wrong in this code or is there any other way to do a synchronous ajax call where the response time is more than 30 seconds.

Comment: does the request work fine using Postman for example? I assume so, since the non-async works fine. I don't know what could be causing that, since it works by just changing the flag. I don't recommend anything sync though, anything (very few exceptions). Just use a callback and switch the async.

Comment: Ajax should never be synchronous, why you want it to be synch? BTW, you said not working on Android, what about other device as desktop? And check your console for error

Comment: As the request to the url is a cross domain request it is not working on the desktop browsers (error on Firefox and Chrome). This Ajax request is running as a part of an app in webview on andriod. I have not checked the behavior of this Ajax call on webview in ios, but will update once I test it.

Comment: Looks like server don't accept synch request, jsonp???  But why you want it synch?

Comment: try this super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);

Comment: I needed the call to be synchronous as I needed to make multiple Ajax calls based on the output of each call. The synchronous call on ios is working fine. I tried all the options on Android but with no affect. So now I have changed the call to a asynchronous request and have divided my operations into multiple callback functions. This way the call is same across devices and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are not able to set a custom timeout for synchronous ajax call... you have to go asynchronous and put your next into .done and .fail ajax calls.

See here: [Login working for Iphone but not android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001182/login-working-for-iphone-but-not-android).